# CCMenuItemImage toggle isSelected (possible?)

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Is it possible to toggle CCMenuItemImage programatically between selected and notSelected?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CCMenuItemToggle is what you're looking for, some sample usage

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/13360

but if what you mean is to toggle between selected and normal image of your CCMenuItemImage, then just call

```
[myMenuItemImage selected];
[myMenuItemImage unselected];
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by remove?

You can hide it with `menuItem.visible = NO`. Since `CCMenu` and `CCMenuItem` both inherit from `CCNode` you can remove them by using the standard approach used through all cocos2d (`removeChild:` or `removeChildByTag:`)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can remove it by calling removeChild, like [menu removeChild:menuItem cleanup:YES];

Comment: Yup, was thinking about some menu specific issue (I always coded menus by hand in cocos2d, skipping CCMenus), you can invoke removeChild for sure, the all are CCNodes

Comment: guys why in the world did I get a -1 for asking a question?

Comment: Don't ask me, I didn't do anything :(